# SVG use element to clone SVG

Tags: svg, d3.js

Is it possible to "use" a whole other svg within a separate svg?  I want to use an map generated with d3 as an icon on the same page.  This is what I tried but it doesn't work.

```
 <svg id="map">
    svg stuff here
 </svg>


 <svg id="bar"> 
     svg stuff here
     <use xlink:href="#map" height="20" width="30" ...>
 </svg>
```

Also tried the cloning approach but ended up with an entire svg within another svg and couldn't get it to scale.  eg. makeicon("#map", "#icon")

```
function makeicon(source, destination) {
    //https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/d3-js/-EEgqt29wmQ
    var src = d3.select(source);
    var dest = d3.select(destination);

    if (!src.empty() && !dest.empty()) {

        var newNode = d3.select(dest.node().insertBefore(src.node().cloneNode(true),
            src.node().nextSibling))
            .attr("id", "newnode")
            .attr("width", null)  // remove height and width of original svg
            .attr("height", null)

            .attr("viewBox", "0 0 20 30");   // try to make it smaller

        return newNode;
```

Comment: Ended up creating a number of jpgs of the chart and using these as the icons.  Quicker but not as satisfying!  Will leave this question open for a bit in case anyone has any other suggestions.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you create the jpgs? (assuming you did it programmatically from the d3-generated svg?)

Answer (score 3):

It should work fine.

Here's a simple example that works fine in Firefox, Opera and Chrome: 
http://jsfiddle.net/gew54/

Source:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <style type='text/css'>
            svg {
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg id="map" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
            <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="lime"/>
        </svg>
        <svg id="bar" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
            <use xlink:href="#map" />
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not on safari though and I need it to work on browsers that render svg. Sigh!

Answer (score 0):

Considering very limited support at the moment (*Gecko engines only*), this can be done using the CSS 3 [`element()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/element) function.

The MDN docs also specifies your case as a common use case:

> ... A particularly useful scenario for using this would be to render an
>   image in an HTML <canvas> element, then use that as a
>   background.

---

#### [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7XG65/2/)

Comment: Limited support is an issue.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [svgWeb](http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/) to make it work in webkit browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Since SVG 2, the [ xlink:href ] attribute is deprecated in favor of [ href ].

```
<use xlink:href="#myId" />
```

> Deprecated: This feature is no longer recommended. Though some
> browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed from
> the relevant web standards, may be in the process of being dropped, or
> may only be kept for compatibility purposes. Avoid using it, and
> update existing code if possible; see the compatibility table at the
> bottom of this page to guide your decision. Be aware that this feature
> may cease to work at any time. [INFO...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use)

```
<use href="#myId" />
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 30 10" width="300" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle id="myCircle" cx="5" cy="5" r="4" stroke="blue"/>
  <use href="#myCircle" x="10" fill="blue"/>
  <use href="#myCircle" x="20" fill="white" stroke="red"/>
  <!--
stroke="red" will be ignored here, as stroke was already set on myCircle.
Most attributes (except for x, y, width, height and (xlink:)href)
do not override those set in the ancestor.
That's why the circles have different x positions, but the same stroke value.
  -->
</svg>
```

[Demo-codepen.io](https://codepen.io/pedro404/pen/JjJRjPm)