# Two bar charts from same data object using D3.js

Tags: d3.js

I have this type of data:

```
[
    {
        "techno":"mongodb", 
        "bu":"london",
        "level":3,
        "number":2, 
        "project": {   
            "level":4, 
            "number":5
        }
    }
]
```

I want to create 2 bar charts side by side from this data.

Here is my code:

```
function draw(dataset) {
    //Largeur et hauteur du graphe

    var barPadding = 2; //Padding des barres
    var nbb = dataset.length;
    var larg = nbb * 30;
    var haut = 100;
    var lb = ((larg - nbb)/nbb);
    var hb = (haut / d3.max(dataset, function(d){
        return d.effectifs;
    }))

    //Create SVG element
    var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", larg)
        .attr("height", haut);

    svg.selectAll(".actuel")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class", "actuel")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {
            return (i * lb); //Largeur de barre de 20 + 1 de padding
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
            return haut - (d.effectifs * hb); // Hauteur moins la valeur de la donnée
        })
        .attr("width", lb - barPadding)
        .attr("height", function(d) {
            return (d.effectifs * 200); // Valeur de la donnée
        })
        .attr("fill", function(d){
            return d3.rgb(255,(d.niveau)*50,255);
        });

    svg.selectAll("text")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .text(function(d){
            return d.effectifs;
        })
        .attr("x", function(d,i){
            return (i * lb) + 12;
        })
        .attr("y", function(d,i){
            return haut -((d.effectifs * hb)-12);
        })
        .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
        .attr("size", 12)
        .attr("fill", "white")
    }
</script>
```

Does anyone have an idea how to procede ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by :

> I want to create 2 bar charts side by side from this data.

1. If you want to duplicate the same chart, you can use SVG 'use' element :

   - doc : http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#UseElement
   - example here [SVG use element to clone SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341679/svg-use-element-to-clone-svg)
2. If your question is about positioning two charts next to each other, wrap your charts in  containers, and translate the second container next to the first :

   ```
   var container1 = svg.append('g')
                            .attr('id','container1');

   var container2 = svg.append('g')
                            .attr('id', 'container2');

   container1.selectAll('.actuel')
             .data(dataset)...
             //Create the chart1 here

   container2.selectAll('.actuel')
             .data(dataset)...
             //Create the chart2 here

   container2.attr('transform','translate('+ svgWidth/2 +',0)'); //To move the g container to the right.
   ```

where svgWidth is the width you gave to your svg, assuming your charts use half of the width for themselves.

Hope that answers your question !